# How to do Group by and count in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using

```
Django==1.10.6
djangorestframework==3.6.2
```

**I have tried so far but i am getting key error**

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, Sum, Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

class SalesReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = imodels.Sales.objects.all()
    serializer_class = iserializers.SalesReportSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        data = imodels.Sales.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(c=Count('id')).values('month', 'c')
        return data
```

**models.py**

```
class Sales(models.Model):

    orig_quantity = 0

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    sold_to = models.ForeignKey(Merchant)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class SalesReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sales
        #fields = ['id', 'quantity', 'total']
        fields = '__all__'
```

> error i am getting KeyError at /sales-report/ "Got KeyError when
>   attempting to get a value for field `quantity` on serializer
>   `SalesReportSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict`
>   instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'quantity'.

Answer (score 0):

Your queryset is wrong. It is not even queryset now:

```
data = (imodels.Sales.objects
        .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date'))
        .values('month')
        .annotate(c=Count('id'))
        .values('month', 'c')  # After this call you will receive list of dicts
                               # [{"month": ..., 'c': ...}, ...]
```

So result of your method 'get_queryset' is a dict that does not have field `quantity`. Serializer tells you about that in error.

Try add all values that are required by serializer to last `values` call.

Comment: Still not working ,
data = (imodels.Sales.objects
        .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date'))
        .values('month')
        .annotate(c=Sum('quantity'))
        .values('id', 'month', 'quantity', 'desc', 'date', 'product'))  # After this call you will receive list of dicts
        return data

now error is
'int' object has no attribute 'pk'